# config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4 application is throwing the errors during the startup with development. I use mongodb for DB.

```
flex/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for #<Flex::Application:0x007f49ec793870> (NoMethodError)
```

**Ruby version** ruby 2.0.0dev (2013-02-08 trunk 39161)

pls help on this

Comment: How did you fix this?